# How to write to a boost::asio::mutable_buffer?

Tags: c++, boost, buffer, boost-asio

I have some code that provides me with a pointer to a buffer, and the buffer's size that I need to fill with data.  I represent this buffer with a `boost::asio::mutable_buffer` instance, but how do I properly use this buffer (e.g. write a string to it, ...) and have boost enforce the buffer boundaries?

Here's some pseudo code:

```
size_t some_callback(void *ptr, size_t) {
    // this function is called by 3rd party
    return our_handler(boost::asio::mutable_buffer(ptr, size));
}

size_t our_handler(const boost::asio::mutable_buffer &buffer)
{
    const std::string test("test");
    // How do I write this string into my buffer?
    return test.size();
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`boost::asio::buffer_cast<>()` is what you should use to get access to the pointer used by the buffer.
`boost::asio::buffer_size()` is what you should use to get access to the size used.

e.g.

```
const std::string test("test");
const size_t len = std::min(boost::asio::buffer_size(mybuf), test.length());
memcpy(boost::asio::buffer_cast<void *>(mybuf),
    test.c_str(),
    len);
const std::string test2("test");
boost::asio::mutable_buffer offset = mybuf + len;
const size_t len2 = std::min(boost::asio::buffer_size(offset), test2.length());
memcpy(boost::asio::buffer_cast<void *>(offset),
    test.c_str(),
    len2);

boost::asio::mutable_buffer offset2 = offset + len2;
```

See also:

- [`buffer_cast()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer_cast.html)
- [`buffer_size()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer_size.html)

Comment: Ok, I knew about the buffer_cast but I thought that the idea was that boost enforces the buffer boundaries through some methods, but if I do the memcpy myself it's up to me to make sure I don't overrun...

Comment: Yes, please don't overrun. ;)

Comment: On the bright side, as you manipulate the buffer (`operator+()`), it returns smaller and smaller buffers.  Totally sane behavior!

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about operator+(), seems handy!